# University campus network structure?

Tags: ip-address

As part of my networking course, I am studying public/private ips; which got me thinking,

Do college campuses have just one public ip which is shared among students and staff, or does it have multiple public ips? I am trying to get a high level picture of how a network might be structured at a university level?

Comment: https://www.ucl.ac.uk/isd/services/get-connected/wired-networks/about-wired-networks/ucl-network-topology

Comment: I doubt that all colleges on earth take the same approach

Comment: Something no one else has mentioned - there are limitations to NAT and its unlikely any reasonably large institution would be able to get awat with a single address. (They may use a pool of IPs alongside NAT to deal with these limitations)

Answer (score 3):

Most major universities have been around long enough that their net blocks were assigned before ipv4 address exhaustion was a widely-recognized issue and, therefore, before NAT became commonplace.  As a result, they tend to have rather large chunks of the ipv4 address space allocated to them.  I do department-level sys/netadmin work at a major university and we have a /16 (plus a few independent /24s) allocated to our institution.

You can use the `whois` database to get information about an organization's IP address allocation if there's a specific university you're curious about:

```
$ host stanford.edu
stanford.edu has address 171.67.215.200
$ whois -h whois.arin.net 171.67.215.200
<snip>
NetRange:       171.64.0.0 - 171.67.255.255
CIDR:           171.64.0.0/14
<snip>
$ host mit.edu
mit.edu has address 104.74.224.87
$ whois 104.74.224.87
<snip>
NetRange:       104.64.0.0 - 104.127.255.255
<snip>
```

...and so on.

However, both due to the ongoing explosion in the number of network-connected devices and for security reasons, my institution (and I would expect most major universities) also uses private IP address ranges internally for things such as wifi networks, groups of public terminals, internal administrative VLANs, etc.  In our case, the central IT group assigns regions of 10.0.0.0/8 for these purposes.

While it's possible that some smaller institutions may use a single public-facing IP address and NAT everything through that one address, I would be *extremely* surprised if any major university did so.  Not only for the historical reasons mentioned in my first paragraph, but also because NAT requires a unique port number for each NATted connection and, at least for my institution, there simply aren't enough port numbers to go around.

Comment: Does each router -in a university campus- have its own public facing ip address?

Comment: @Dude - The gateway addresses for each VLAN are, of course, within that VLAN's address range (e.g., the gateway for x.y.z.0/24 would usually be x.y.z.1), so if it's a gateway for a public block, that address will also be public. But that's a virtual router, since it's for a VLAN. I don't know whether the actual physical hardware has public or private addresses, but I assume they're probably public (and heavily firewalled!).